# Transpose in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to transpose a table where rows become columns and the values needs to be replace by default if its null.

Below is my table

```
|col1    |aa     |bb     |def |
--------------------------------
|min val |null   |null   |100 |
|max val |500    |null   |1000|
```

I am expecting the output as below

```
|segment |min val  |max val|
-------------------------
|aa      |100      |500    |
|bb      |100      |1000   |
```

Whenever any value is null, it needs to get replaced with def value. I have tried pivoting and I couldn't arrive at my expected result. I am looking for a query in SQL Server.

Below is what I tried.

```
SELECT Name, [min val], [max val]
FROM (
    SELECT col1, aa,bb
    FROM OriginalTable
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(aa) AS aa, MAX(bb) AS bb
    FOR col1 IN ([min val], [max val])
) AS PivotedTable;
```

Comment: The terminology you need, which would help you find many similar questions/answers, is *pivoting* not *transposing*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit simpler answer:

```sql
SELECT  segment
-- Conditional aggregation pivot
,   max(CASE WHEN col1 = 'min val' THEN isnull(value, def) END) AS min_val
,   max(CASE WHEN col1 = 'max val' THEN isnull(value, def) END) AS max_val
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'min val', NULL,NULL, 100)
    ,   (N'max val', 500, NULL, 1000)
) t (col1,[aa],[bb],def)    -- Data
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES('aa', aa), ('bb', bb)
    ) x (segment, value)    -- Unpivot
GROUP BY segment
```

I prefer to use manual pivot/unpivot operators for clarity.

First you want to create rows from columns aa, bb. For this i use the values construct to create two rows from the two columns (UNPIVOT).

The second part is that you want to create columns from two rows. This is the  PIVOT. The conditional aggregation pattern is very simple way of gathering columns from multiple rows. By using CASE WHEN, we get either the value or NULL if the row doesn't match our condition. By wrapping it in a MAX aggregate, it ensures that any non-null value will be returned ahead of NULLs which is what we want.

Finally, as a little detail, you want to fallback to default value. This is done by ISNULL(value, def) inside the conditional aggregation.

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more detailed in my explanation. My table as close to 11 Million records and manually adding the values is not possible.

Comment: i just used values as example, you can just substitute it with select from your real table :)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial table is already a transposition (or "pivot"), so to get the column headings of that as rows in the desired result you need to "unpivot" first. e.g:

```
   SELECT
          col1
        , segment
        ,  NULLIF(value,0) value
        , MIN(case when value > 0 then value end) OVER() minmin
        , SUM(value) OVER(partition by segment) as num
    FROM (
        SELECT
              col1
            , coalesce(aa,0) aa
            , coalesce(bb,0) bb
            , coalesce(def,0) def
        FROM your_table
        ) AS src
    UNPIVOT(value FOR segment IN (aa, bb, def)) AS unpvt
```

| col1 | segment | value | minmin | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| min val | aa | *null* | 100 | 500 |
| max val | aa | 500 | 100 | 500 |
| max val | bb | *null* | 100 | 0 |
| min val | bb | *null* | 100 | 0 |
| min val | def | 100 | 100 | 1100 |
| max val | def | 1000 | 100 | 1100 |

Once we have the data in rows it becomes simple to calculate minimum and maximums, but there are some added "tweaks" needed to eliminate segment bb which has no valid values, and we need to supply an overall minimum for the absent value in segment aa. These are provided by using coalesce to supply zeros if null, then summing per segment so to eliminate any sums of zero. The overall minimum is calculated via another window function. With the data now setup this way we can do the final aggregates for MIN/MAX:

```
SELECT
      segment
    , MIN(CASE WHEN col1 = 'min val' THEN coalesce(value,minmin) END) AS min_val
    , MAX(CASE WHEN col1 = 'max val' THEN value END) AS max_val
FROM (
    SELECT
          col1
        , segment
        , NULLIF(value,0) value
        , MIN(case when value > 0 then value end) OVER() minmin
        , SUM(value) OVER(partition by segment) as num
    FROM (
        SELECT
              col1
            , coalesce(aa,0) aa
            , coalesce(bb,0) bb
            , coalesce(def,0) def
        FROM your_table
        ) AS src
    UNPIVOT(value FOR segment IN (aa, bb, def)) AS unpvt
  ) AS calc
WHERE NUM > 0
GROUP BY segment;
```

| segment | min_val | max_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 100 | 500 |
| def | 100 | 1000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1ut24_UP)